# Chrome: Notification onshow event not triggering

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, notifications, service-worker

I'm trying to run code in my service worker once a notification is shown.
I'm displaying notifications using this API:

```
self.registration.showNotification(title, options)
```

I've tried few stuff:

1. I was hoping the promise returned is fulfilled with `Notification` object, then I can do stuff after it's shown. But the promise if fulfilled with `undefined`.
2. I was trying to attach a function like that (before the showNotification call of course):

   `Notification.onshow = function() { console.log('shown')};`

but it isn't triggered (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notification/onshow)

3. I was trying to do something similar to attach a callback to notifictionclick and notificationclose events:

   `self.addEventListener("notificationshow", (event) => {});`

Also, didn't work.

My main objective basically is to get the notification instance after it's shown so I can do stuff to it (for example call `notifiaction.close` )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `getNotifications` (and filter by tag to get your notification)

```
var options = { tag : 'user_alerts' };

navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(function(registration) {
  registration.getNotifications(options).then(function(notifications) {
    // do something with your notifications
    notifications[0].close();
  }) 
});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerRegistration/getNotifications